# Azure devops optional stage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, devops

I have a yaml pipeline that builds and deploys a project. it deploys to dev & tst. But i dont always want to deploy to tst. at the moment i have solved this with approvals. when the dev stage finishes the pipeline waits for approval.

this introduces some problems:

- all developers get an email every time, which can be annoying.
- the pipeline waits for deployment to tst, even when deploymen to tst isnt needed. it keeps
  waiting
- new ci builds dont start when the pipeline is waiting

Comment: Is there a specific condition you could check on? Because if there is, you can [specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) on a job or stage.

Comment: is the yaml triggered automatically or manually?

Comment: How do you handle approvals? If you use environment and approvals from it you should be able to run another CI.

Comment: i just set my approvals to expire in 30 minutes

Comment: what framework, language your project has ? may be you can make a small pearl script for that which will only do the required jobs for example cache cleaning, compiling views, assets only, I had the similar issue with the laravel php project so i came up with small script which let me do the deployment without doing all reboots in services

Answer (score 1):

If there is a well defined way how to determine whether to run the tst stage or not, you can either [specify a custom condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions) on the stage or [conditionally include the stage using an expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-run-a-step)

## Specify a condition

[From the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions)

> You can specify the conditions under which each stage, job, or step
> runs. By default, a job or stage runs if it does not depend on any
> other job or stage, or if all of the jobs or stages that it depends on
> have completed and succeeded.

There are a number of ways you can customize this behavior, either by built in or custom defined conditions, for example, to run tun the tst stage only if the branch is `main`:

```
stages:
- stage: dev
  jobs:
  - job: dev1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello from dev!

- stage: tst
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
  jobs:
  - job: tst1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello From tst!
```

The tst stage will still be visible when you open the pipeline run, it will be marked as skipped

The `condition` under the tst stage can be altered to fit your need (it can include both [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#run-if-a-variable-is-set-to-true), [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-template-parameter-as-part-of-a-condition) and even [output from previous stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-the-output-variable-from-a-job-in-a-condition-in-a-subsequent-job).

## Conditional expression

[From the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-run-a-step)

> You can use if, elseif, and else clauses to conditionally assign
> variable values or set inputs for tasks. You can also conditionally
> run a step when a condition is met.

Conditional insertion only works with template syntax, which is evaluated when the pipeline yaml is compiled (i.e before the pipeline starts). Thus it cannot evaluate output of previous steps. In the below example the tst stage is completely removed from the pipeline run when the pipeline is instantiated (and the template compiled) if the branch is not `main`

```
stages:
- stage: dev
  jobs:
  - job: dev1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello from dev!
- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main') }}:
  - stage: tst
    jobs:
    - job: tst1
      steps:
        - script: echo Hello From tst!
```

Comment: To add on to this, we've defined a parameter in our yaml script. The parameters show up in the DevOps portal as dropdowns, checkboxes, etc. Some of our parameters are conditions for whether stages should be built.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this solves the issue, which is: you have a pipeline with 2 stages - you always want the first stage to run, but only *sometimes* the second. Having parameters/conditions for the second stage assumes you know whether you want to run that second stage before running the pipeline. We also don't want to run the whole pipeline again with a different parameter set. What I'm after is similar functionality to the legacy "release" view, where you can deploy a version to a lower environment, and at a later point in time, deploy that same version to a higher environment.

Comment: We could create a second pipeline that we only manually trigger, but: A) this doesn't enforce the necessary predecessor stages . B) it doesn't provide a holistic view of commit -> production

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but it feels like the Azure YAML pipelines has been designed exclusively with continuous *deployment* in mind, not continuous *delivery* (where you keep software releasable, but choose when you release)

Comment: @DavidMasters it solves the issue given that *there is a well defined way to determine whether to run the tst stage or not*, then you can formulate that as a condition. If there is no such well defined condition (i.e the release happens through a business decision or through will), you will need to use environment approvals or classical pipelines (which unfortunately does not support yaml definitions). Your observation is correct that yaml pipelines indeed are very continuous delivery focused.

Comment: An option for more sophisticated logic than environment approvals offer (or to even provide your own GUI for approvals) could be to look into gates, which for example can call outside REST API's for approvals or rejection of a pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates